# Accessing a sub attribute in a XML file using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, printing, linq-to-xml, xelement

In C#, I am trying to change an option of a feature in an XML file which presents a Print Ticket and loaded as an `XElement` by the following code:

```
XElement ticketRootXElement = null;
using (Stream ticketReadStream = displayedPrintTicket.GetReadStream())
{
   ticketRootXElement = XElement.Load(ticketReadStream);
}
```

The partial XML is something like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<psf:Feature xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework" name="psk:PageMediaSize">
    <psf:Option name="psk:ISOA4">
        <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:MediaSizeWidth">
            <psf:Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:integer">210000</psf:Value>
        </psf:ScoredProperty>
        <psf:ScoredProperty name="psk:MediaSizeHeight">
            <psf:Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:integer">297000</psf:Value>
        </psf:ScoredProperty>
    </psf:Option>
</psf:Feature>
```

How can I access the "Option" of a specific "Feature" and change it to something like 
`<psf:Option name="psk:ISOA3">`?

I tried the following code, but it fails.

```
foreach (XAttribute xAttr in ticketRootXElement.Descendants(xns_psf + "Feature").Attributes())
{
   if (xAttr.Value.Equals("psk:PageMediaSize"))
   {
      foreach(XAttribute xSubAttr in ticketRootXElement.Element("PageMediaSize").Descendants(xns_psf + "Option").Attributes())
      {
         if (xAttr.NextAttribute.Name.LocalName.Equals("name"))
         {
            xAttr.NextAttribute.SetValue("psk:ISO" + cmb_PaperSize.SelectedValue.ToString());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can modify the option value of your selected feature as as follows:

```
var featureName = "psk:PageMediaSize";
var newOptionValue = "psk:ISOA3"; // Your modified value here

XNamespace xns_psf = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08/printing/printschemaframework";
var query = from f in ticketRootXElement.DescendantsAndSelf(xns_psf + "Feature")
            where (string)f.Attribute("name") == featureName
            select f;
foreach (var f in query)
{
    // TODO: handle the situation were a child <psf:Option> element is missing.
    f.Element(xns_psf + "Option").SetAttributeValue("name", newOptionValue);
}
```

Notes:

- [`XElement.Attribute(XName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Attribute_System_Xml_Linq_XName_) can be used to look up an attribute by name, and [`XElement.SetAttributeValue(XName, Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_SetAttributeValue_System_Xml_Linq_XName_System_Object_) can be used to set or add an attribute value by name.
- [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute_op_Explicit_System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute__System_String) an `XAttribute` to a `string` returns the value of the attribute, or `null` if the attribute was missing, and so is convenient to use when filtering by attribute value in a `where` statement.
- If the selected `<psf:Feature>` element does not have a child `<psf:Option>` element, the above code will throw an exception.  You will need to check your XML schema to determine whether this is possible, and if so, how to handle it.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tcmp5o).

Comment: Actually I did it using the following code. But your solution sounds much better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did it using the following code. But "bdc" solution (above answer) sounds much better:

```
var element = ticketRootXElement.Descendants(xns_psf + "Feature")
              .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("name").Value == "psk:PageMediaSize")
              .Single();

var subelement = element.Descendants(xns_psf + "Option")
                .Single();

subelement.FirstAttribute.SetValue("psk:ISOA3");
```